# add geom_hline legend without screwing up geom_line legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to draw a simple (scree)-plot with some extra `geom_hline` and `geom_vline`s thrown in.

Problem is: whenever I so much as add `show_guide=TRUE` *or* add some `aes()` to the `geom_xline`, I screw up the original legend.

Here's some (ugly) fake data:

```
exdf <- data.frame(rep(x=1:12, times = 3), rep(x = c("A", "B", "C"), times = 6), rnorm(36), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(exdf) <- c("PC", "variable", "eigenvalue")
```

And here's my plot:

```
g <- ggplot(data = exdf, mapping = aes(x = factor(PC), y = eigenvalue))
g <- g + geom_line(mapping = aes(group = factor(variable), linetype = variable))
g <- g + geom_vline(xintercept = 7, colour = "green", show_guide = TRUE)
```

[image]
[image]

How do I add a separate legend for the `geom_vline` without polluting the other legend?

Can't wrap my head around why one layer's color would change that of another *legend*.

Comment: Do you mean you want a separate legend for `geom_vline`? Your example is vertical, but your end question says "hline".

Comment: sorry, mistake – corrected. I meant `geom_vline`.

Answer (score 3):

This partly solves the problem:

```
g <- ggplot(data = exdf, mapping = aes(x = factor(PC), y = eigenvalue))
g <- g + geom_line(mapping = aes(group = factor(variable), linetype = variable))
g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = x, colour = Threshold), data.frame(x = 7, Threshold = "A"), show_guide = TRUE) + scale_colour_manual(values = c(A = "green")
```

[image]

But the legend will still have crosses for the variable section, albeit not green ones.

Alternatively you could use a geom_line with a new data frame with two rows, both with the same x and y equal to the lower and upper bounds of your data. This will give you a legend that has a horizontal green line for your threshold and no vertical lines.

Comment: thanks @Nick K – I added a plot.
I need to get rid of the vertical lines in the axes, though – and I also need `hline`s, which will also screw up the the linetype of the variable legend.
Might just have to do it with `annotate()` for now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Nick K's suggestion in the above, here's a way to do this with **clean legends** via different `data =` for the different layers.

```
    exdf <- data.frame(rep(x=1:12, times = 3), rep(x = c("A", "B", "C"), times = 6), rnorm(36), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(exdf) <- c("PC", "variable", "eigenvalue") 
    g <- ggplot()
    g <- g + geom_line(data = exdf, mapping = aes(x = factor(PC), y = eigenvalue, group = factor(variable), linetype = variable))
    g
    thresholds <- data.frame(threshold = "Threshold-A", PC = 7, ymin = min(exdf$eigenvalue), ymax = max(exdf$eigenvalue))
    g <- g + geom_linerange(data = thresholds, mapping = aes(x = PC, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, color = threshold))
    g
```

yields:

[image: clean-legend]

Notice:

- I know, the original data `exdf` are dumb and make an ugly plot; that's not the point here.
- Notice that you have to set the `data =` argument for *both* layers, and keep the first `g <- ggplot()` blank, otherwise ggplot2 gets confused about the dataframes.
- yeah, it's a hack job (see below), and it also doesn't fill the y-height of the plot, as a `geom_vline` should.

---

As an add-on, (**not a solution!**), here's how it *should* work with `geom_vline`:

```
exdf <- data.frame(rep(x=1:12, times = 3), rep(x = c("A", "B", "C"), times = 6), rnorm(36), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(exdf) <- c("PC", "variable", "eigenvalue") 
g <- ggplot()
g <- g + geom_line(data = exdf, mapping = aes(x = factor(PC), y = eigenvalue, group = factor(variable), linetype = variable))
g
g + geom_vline(data = thresholds, mapping = aes(xintercept = PC, color = threshold), show_guide = TRUE)
```

yields:

[image: messy legend via geom_vline]

That fills the yheight, as you would expect from `geom_vline`, but *somehow* messes up the legend of `variable` (notice the vertical lines).

Not sure why this is so, feels like a bug to me.
Here reported: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1267